# Help to understand a simple example of clist in expl3

Tags: expl3

Sorry if my question is elemental. I have start learning `LaTeX` a month ago. I'm learning at the same time as have new ideas. That being said, someone could help me to understand a simple example of `clist` in `expl3`? What's wrong with this code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareListOfValues}{ m m }
{
    \clist_new:N  \g_list_of_values_#1
    \clist_set:Nn \g_list_of_values_#1 {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetValueFromList}{ m m }
{
    \clist_item:Nn \g_list_of_values_#1 {#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareListOfValues{FirstList}{1.11, 1.22}

\begin{document}
    \GetValueFromList{FirstList}{2} % -> 1.22
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use the `c` variants instead of `N`, i.e. `\clist_new:c {g_list_of_values_#1}` etc.

Comment: The `g_` prefix denotes a global variable; for this you should use `\clist_gset:Nn` (or the variant `\clist_gset:cn` for your special case). Use local variables (having prefix `l_`) with `\clist_set:Nn`. Whether you want a local or a global variable depends on the use you do of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just tack  `#1` on to the end of a variable name. Instead you should use `\clist_new:c`, which takes a "command name". In fact, as Joesph points out in the comments, it is better to use `\clist_gclear_new:c`. Although not mandatory, the recommended style is to end your clist varaible names with `clist`.

Here is a corrected version of your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareListOfValues}{ m m }
{
    \clist_gclear_new:c {g_list_of_values_#1_clist}
    \clist_gset:cn {g_list_of_values_#1_clist} {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetValueFromList}{ m m }
{
    \clist_item:cn {g_list_of_values_#1_clist} {#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareListOfValues{FirstList}{1.11, 1.22}

\begin{document}
    \GetValueFromList{FirstList}{2} % -> 1.22
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I changed it to `\clist_gset:cn` since the OP had global variables.

Comment: I'd use `\clist_gclear_new:c` as the user-level says 'declare'

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. Done.